# Text overflowing the sides of its container div

Tags: html, css

My text inside the containing div overflows it from the sides where it should be actually wrapping automatically.

```css
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #E4E4E4;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <p>jjfaljfejjfkadjf;lj;jmvwutpvwjfjdsjfklsdkdfjklsjfkljwjeiojfklslfkjsvfoiwjeorfjviw nfwvfjojwkdsklflskjfvwiernvejveurvnwejfkdsjwjjrfjiowjeionvkjlksjdfkljkljdwijiodjfiovnwjoiejoijfiojkjsljfdkjslfiejskdklfjlksjfeijskdjfklsjkldjfwjnfklsjfwoevjnwfdjshfk
      fsdkjfsjdfkjksjdfkjsljfdkljskl
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is what is displayed:

[image: Screenshot]

I have read other questions but none of them solves my issue. The thing is that the text does not overflow the bottom of the div. Is it something to do with the width I have set for the div?

Comment: It works as it is http://jsfiddle.net/VVEjV/

Comment: Everything's fine on my end, tested the code, no problems whatsoever. I don't know what's causing your issue, but it's not the code.

Comment: @Jon which browser are you using? btw pawan you can siomple use `word-wrap: break-word;` but I don't see any issue here in your provided markup

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Both FF and Chrome.

Comment: @Jon didn't got an overflow in his provided content but yes if I added a long string it happens

Comment: @TerryHarvey no if we do add more strings without any space it does overflow but just I simply made a fiddle out of his provided markup I don't see any issue as such

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand now. because the string was a single word, it didnt break. using multiple words, it does break.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will wrap your text within the div, even if your string is unbroken (which is what I assume you mean).

```
.wordwrap {  
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* Webkit */    
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */     
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */    
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */     
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see what you mean, the final K slightly overlaps the edge of the div in Chrome.

I would suggest removing the second 5px in your padding and just have:

```
padding:  5px;
```

Also add in :

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

That way you get 5px padding around the entire div and your content will be wrapped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a very long word. You can do as they said, with `word-wrap: break-word;`, or you can hide the text.

You can use text-overflow, i.e:

```
p {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Where:

`text-overflow: clip|ellipsis|string;`

[More info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)